# Add space between nodes with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a string of HTML where I want to strip all the html tags. The problem is that the plain text of each node is squished together and I need to add some whitespace between each node.

```
Nokogiri::HTML("<p>Hello</p><p>There</p>").text
Gives  => HelloThere
I want => Hello There
```

Can I tell Nokogiri to behave like this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<p>Hello</p><p>There</p>")
doc.xpath('//text()').to_a.join(" ")
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not only p tags. It can be any html tag.

Comment: Seems to work. Don't know how efficient it is but I'll do this :) Thanks

Comment: @Linus I think [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23680309/2767755) more accurate, as per your comment. Mine will select all texts, if they wrapped inside tag or not. Although I don't know your actual use-case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Nokogiri::HTML("<p>Hello</p><p>There</p>").xpath("//*[not(child::*)]").map(&:text).join(' ')
# => "Hello There"
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not how the HTML looks. It looks like in my question. I cannot control how the HTML is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I tried to do it on my own but ended using a solution which slightly looks like Uri Agassi's :)

```
irb(main):040:0> Nokogiri::HTML("<p>Hello</p><p>There</p>").xpath("//text()").map(&:text).join(" ")
=> "Hello There"
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not how the HTML looks. It looks like in my question. I cannot control how the HTML is formatted. Do I really have to loop over all elements and add a space character? Seems ridiculous...